# tkinter: value in label bouncing back to previous value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an extremely simple clicker game with tkinter and I am wondering why does the number in the label bounces back to the previous number

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

value = 0

# manual adder
def add_one(value):
    value += 1
    testLabel["text"] = str(value)


# auto adder
# will somehow bounce back to some previous value
def first_auto(value):
    value += 1
    testLabel["text"] = str(value)
    root.after(1000, first_auto, value)
    # just for testing random stuff
    # if value > 10:
    #     myLabel.grid(column=1, row=2)
    

def turnoff():
    autoButton["state"] = DISABLED

# is them widgets
testLabel = Label(root, text= str(value))
addButton = Button(root, text="Add 1", command=lambda: add_one(int(testLabel["text"])))
autoButton = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: [first_auto(int(testLabel["text"])), turnoff()])
exitButton = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
myLabel = Label(root, text="larger than 10, stop")

# putting the widgets on screen
testLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
addButton.grid(column=0, row=1)
autoButton.grid(column=0, row=2)
exitButton.grid(column=1, row=1)


root.mainloop()
```

I have 2 buttons, a manual add which adds one each click, and an auto adder which adds 1 every second. The problem I am experiencing is while the auto adder is on (turned on when value on label is 10) and I click to 20 before the auto adder adds 1, the value somehow bounces back to 17 instead of adding 1 to 20.

It somehow did not get the current value in the label and I do not know why

Comment: Right, because your `root.after` call is not fetching the current value of the edit box.  It's passing whatever the `first_auto` call received, plus 1.  If you want these methods to deal with the actual label control, then just have them read and write `testlabel["text"]` directly.  This stuff where you're fetching the data in one place and storing it in another is a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem you were having with your code and am pretty sure I fixed the issue. For some reason, it was not giving the correct reference to the number inside the label with two different functions incrementing it without referencing the global variable.

I fixed it by calling `add_one` inside of `first_auto` and removing all the parameters for `value`. Then I referenced the global variable for `value` inside `add_one`. Below is an example of the updated code...

```
def add_one():
    global value
    value += 1
    testLabel["text"] = str(value)

def first_auto():
    add_one()
    root.after(1000, first_auto)

addButton = Button(root, text="Add 1", command=add_one)
autoButton = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: [first_auto(), turnoff()])
```